# Two separate UIButtons sharing same press... can't press two at one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uikit

I have a view set up as a game controller for an UIImageView on my screen. I have two directional arrows left/right, and an A and B button.

When the user holds a directional (touch down) it moves the player, and on the touch Up method it stops.

However, while holding a directional UIButton, the other UIButtons will not function until you release the touch Up on the directional, thus delaying the tap.

Also, say if you held the A button down and simply tap a directional once, the A button will register the directional button being touched down instead of A, even though A will be in its highlighted state.

I have checked the connections for everything, they are all separate UIButton instances with only those actions linked.

It seems that a touchUp method is being passed to another UIButton instance making two presses at the same time impossible. I have not had issues with this before.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please post screenshot.

Comment: What should i show for a screen shot?

Comment: You need to process touch events yourself, or at least use `UIGestureRecognizer`s.

Answer (score 2):

Check that [multipleTouchEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/multipleTouchEnabled) is true for parent views:

> **multipleTouchEnabled**
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver handles
>   multi-touch events.

And that [exclusiveTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/exclusiveTouch) is false for buttons:

> **exclusiveTouch**
>
> A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver handles touch
>   events exclusively.